# Running Html on localhost

Tags: html

How do I run a Html file on localhost so other computers can connect to the website on the same network using a Windows 10 machine? I probably messed up about localhost.

Comment: `localhost` is a special dns entry that points to your local computer. If someone else on the network tries to open a browser on their machine and types in `http://localhost`, it will try to connect to THEIR machine, not yours. You need to install a web server, such as Apache or IIS. Once you have that installed, then you can host files from your computer. Finally, they need to connect your internal IP address, not `localhost`

Answer (score 1):

`Localhost` is your local machine, as mentioned in other comments. I assume what you want is to run an `HTTP server` so another computer can access `HTML` files 
 on your machine via their browser?

You can run an `HTTP server` in a number of different ways. For example, with [Python3](https://www.python.org/downloads/):

```
python -m http.server
```

Or manually from within Python3:

```
import http.server
import socketserver

PORT = 8000

Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler) as httpd:
    print("serving at port", PORT)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

You can then get the IP address of your machine with `ipconfig` (Windows), (it'll probably start with 192.168...) and give this to the other person on the same network.

Add a comment if you are stuck and I can help you further.

Comment: I tried that in Windows 10 cmd but it said no command "python"

Comment: You have to have Python installed (see the link) and have it on your path (http://www.anthonydebarros.com/2015/08/16/setting-up-python-in-windows-10/). If that's done try `python3 -m http.server`

Comment: do you do it in CMD or the actual Python Program?

Comment: `cmd`, if python is on your `PATH`. If you can't get that working, I've updated the answer with a Python3 script you can run to do the same thing

Answer (score 0):

run your html file in your local machine host it locally on any port
[ng rok installation and doc](https://ngrok.com/docs)

install ngrok

type in your shell

**ngrok http port number** and send the link generated to others machine they will see your html file

Comment: This application won't be able to host this outside of my home network Right?